# I need hierarchical Query in mysql

Tags: mysql

Need hierarchical Query in mysql. person who introduce another person          record and all others which are introduced by them. Please help me.

```
 | associate_id  |  associate_introducer_id  |
 +---------------+---------------------------+
 |  123          |   999999999               |
 |  234          |   123                     |
 |  456          |   123                     |
 |  431          |   234                     |
 |  567          |   456                     |
```

if user enter 123 then all record display which is introduced by 123 and also there sub record.

Comment: i don't know how to get these records. i am confused about that

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Maybe you wanna update all records with `associate_introducer_id` with the same id to another id?

```
UPDATE your_table_name 
SET associate_introducer_id = '1234' 
WHERE associate_introducer_id = '123'
```